# How to blur the content in text box in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Iam new to WPF. In my WPF windows form I have button and content in text box. I have to blur the content in textbox slowly when user clicks on button. What text style should I use.

Comment: Yeah i don't get it how people cant understand the concept as simple as a tick mark. How do they become s/w engineers ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [BlurEffect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.blureffect.aspx)

Comment: Is the BlurEffect animatable?

Comment: You can use a DoubleAnimation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation.aspx) to animate the Radius property of the BlurEffect (the amount of blur applied) (just as animating the Opacity).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to [animate the Opacity property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771632.aspx).

Comment: I don't think he is trying to make it semi-transparent, but blurred.